# Add another user for remote access Windows 10

Tags: authentication, windows-10, remote-access, remote-desktop

So, I created remote access from my lap top to server(Windows 10). Now, how can I add more users, so they can log in from their lap tops with their microsoft accounts or whatever accounts they have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to create local account. After you do that, go to start/computer/properties/remote/addusers. There, add your newly created user to remote.You type in the RemoteDesktop username LocalAccount\username and password you set.